# Do JUnit tests actually execute code?

Tags: java, testing, junit

Do unit tests in general, and specifically Java unit tests such as JUnit actually run the code? Do they compile and execute it? Or can unit tests be used to check code without actually compiling and executing it?

Answer (score 1):

> Do unit tests in general, and specifically Java unit tests such as
>   JUnit actually run the code?

Yes JUnit calls and execute the code to be tested. That is the whole purpose of Junit testing i.e. to execute the code and build a confidence that it works fine.

> Do they compile and execute it? Or can unit tests be used to check
>   code without actually compiling and executing it?

No java code can be executed without compilation. So the code Junit tests is ofcourse compiled code.

Comment: oops I meant, can it be tested without actually executing the code? For example, if you wanted to test code but you weren't sure if it was malicious, could you use unit testing safely?

Comment: @user2962691 No. Strictly speaking, it's impossible to make something that'll be able to figure out what a piece of code does without running it in the general case; so it's not possible to test code without running it.